# Replacing multiple columns in pandas with multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I'm trying to do a replacing values code using python from csv to pandas. I know there are a lot somehow same questions but i cannot get exactly what I needed even if I have tried them. Basically this is the code that I have tried using:

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Making data frame from the csv file 
raw_data = pd.read_csv("ogimet.csv") 

df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"]= df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].replace(1, "Passed all quality control checks") 
print (df)

#saving the pd
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'oh.csv', index = None, header=True) #Don't forget to add '.csv' at the end of the path
```

The problem is I also have to apply conditions to other columns (wind speed quality, air temperature quality, and dew point quality) and aside from that there are other conditions which represent each number:

- '0':"Passed gross limits check",
- '1':"Passed all quality control
  checks",
- '2':"Suspect",
- '3':"Erroneous",
- '4':"Passed gross limits
  check, data originate from an NCEI data source", '
- 5':"Passed all quality control checks, data originate from an NCEI data source",
- '6':"Suspect, data originate from an NCEI data source",
- '7':"Erroneous, data originate from an NCEI data source", '9':"Passed
  gross limits check if elements is present

I have tried doing this one by one, but it seems pretty much crowded:

```
df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"]= df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].replace(2, "Suspect")
df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"]= df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].replace(3, "Erroneous") 
df["WIND SPEED QUALITY"]= df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].replace(2, "Suspect") 
df["WIND SPEED QUALITY"]= df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].replace(3, "Erroneous")
```

So my question is in general is there any other ways to make this in one bit or like a simple version? thank you!

Comment: shure you could perform that using a dict, like objs ={'WIND DIRECTION QUALITY': {'to_replace': 2, 'value': "Spect"}} then with a for loop `for column, value in objs.items(): df[column].replace(**value, in_place=True)` i think some like this should be works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict then apply per column, it may be easier than your current solution. Then you can use the same apply per column

```
change={0:"Passed gross limits check",
1:"Passed all quality control checks",
2:"Suspect",
3:"Erroneous",
4:"Passed gross limits check, data originate from an NCEI data source", 
5:"Passed all quality control checks, data originate from an NCEI data source",
6:"Suspect, data originate from an NCEI data source",
7:"Erroneous, data originate from an NCEI data source", 
9:"Passed gross limits check if elements is present"}


df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].apply(lambda x: change[x] if x in change.keys() else x)
```

you may need to quote the numbers if they are strings in the data.

If you only have those numbers in the column, it get's easier with:

```
df["WIND DIRECTION QUALITY"].map(change)
```

but that only works if your dict matches every item in the data set. I hope this helps

Comment: yes i have tried this one but this affects my other columns... in which I only plan on changing values for a certain column.

Comment: @KrishnaSantos I changed my answer, can you check it to see if that works better as a pattern for you